# Understanding subcommands with go-flags

Tags: go

I'm building a CLI tool to start learning some Go.  I found this popular package that I wanted to use for some commands like this:

http://godoc.org/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags#Group
https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

```
ex list todos
ex list todos --completed
ex list events
ex list todos events
ex authenticate
```

The way I understand it is `ex` would be my main command.
`list` and `authenticate` are subcommands.

But what are `todos` and `events` in this scenario?  And what would be `--completed` be.  Is `--completed` called an `Option`?  That's the verbage I see around, but not sure if I'm reading it correctly.  I'm trying to find an example that has the different options for something like this scenario, but I could not find one.

I tried using urfave/cli which worked at well at first, until I found a requirement to be able to pass multiple entities to `ex list` like `ex list todos events`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used jessevdk/go-flags on multiple projects and really like it. The documentation is sparse, but the code is clean so self-documenting in many ways.

I will try and address your questions as best I can:

`ex` would be your binary, and would usually be a 'master' struct of all the top level commands (eg https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/master/fly/commands/fly.go). This will get parsed in your main function (eg https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/master/fly/main.go).

`todos` and `events` would actually be the first level of subcommands. You would define those on the first level command (`list`) in the same way you define commands on the 'master' command struct.

`--completed` is indeed an option.

One example of an open source project that uses go-flags in the Concourse CI CLI https://github.com/concourse/concourse/tree/master/fly. Although it doesn't you nested commands like you want to do, it gives a pretty solid foundation for go-flags usage.

Comment: At the bottom of fly.go on line 50, there's `var Fly FlyCommand`.  Why is this needed?  Can you not reference the FlyCommand from another package without that declaration on line 50?

Comment: Yea, that's to create an actual 'instance' of the `FlyCommand` struct so that it can get populated with values. You'll see in the `main()` function that the address of that variable is passed in to the parser in `NewParser()`. Then when `Parse()` is called go-flags populates appropriate fields all the way through the command/options structure.